# How to Delete specific template specialization with keyword delete in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, delete-operator

I am trying to understand some use cases of the keyword delete in C++11.

So I tried to delete a specific class template specialization by deleting its constructor in the main method.

Here is my code :

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ComplexNumber
{
   T x;
   T y;    
   public:
      ComplexNumber(T a, T b) : x(a) , y(b) {}        
      void display()  {    std::cout<<x << " + i"<<y<<std::endl;   }
};

int main()
{
    ComplexNumber(char a, char b) = delete;
    ComplexNumber<int> obj1(1,2);
    ComplexNumber<double> obj2(1.0,2.0);
    ComplexNumber<char> obj3('1' , '2');
    return 0;
}
```

But the program execution doesn't block on "ComplexNumber obj3('1' , '2')" as expected, but on the line "ComplexNumber(char a, char b) = delete".

Here is errors' trace:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:28:18: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
ComplexNumber(char a, char b) = delete;
              ^
main.cpp:28:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
ComplexNumber(char a, char b) = delete;
               ^~~~
main.cpp:28:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
ComplexNumber(char a, char b) = delete;
                       ^~~~
main.cpp:28:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
ComplexNumber(char a, char b) = delete;
```

Could you help to understand why we cannot delete a specific constructor "for char type" here?

Comment: You cannot attempt to figure how to do something in C++ by trial and error. You cannot delete a constructor like that C++ does not work this way. You either have to use SFINAE on the constructor so it fails to resolve with specific template parameters, or specialize the entire template for these template parameters and delete the specialization's constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What effect do you want to achieve?

The user gets an error message when trying to instantiate your class with `char`. Here I would use a `static_assert` with a useful message:

```
template <typename T>
class ComplexNumber
{
  static_assert(!std::is_same_v<char, T>, 
                "char is not allowed because .... consider using ??? instead.");

  // ...
};
```

Usually you want to `= delete` one (or more) of your constructors when the constructor itself is a function template:

```
class MyComplexNumber
{
  double _re;
  double _im;

public:
  template <typename T>
  MyComplexNumber(T re, T im) : _re(re), _im(im) { }

  MyComplexNumber(char, char) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. It works by deleting the specific constructor inside the class. But why we Cannot do the same outside the class, have you any explanation ?

Comment: If you could change the constructor of a class in a translation unit, then different translation units would see different rules for the class (e.g. A.cpp deletes char and B.cpp deletes float). Therefore you have to set these rules in the class declaration itself.

Comment: Note that C++17 [introduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) `std::is_same_v<T, U>` as an alias of `std::is_same<T, U>::value`. The latter is available in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

The more idiomatic way of putting a constraint on your template is to use `static_assert`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ComplexNumber
{
   static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, char>);
   T x;
   T y;    
   public:
      ComplexNumber(T a, T b) : x(a) , y(b) {}
      void display()  {    std::cout<<x << " + i"<<y<<std::endl;   }
};

int main()
{
    ComplexNumber<int> obj1(1,2);
    ComplexNumber<double> obj2(1.0,2.0);
    ComplexNumber<char> obj3('1' , '2');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ComplexNumber
{
   T x;
   T y;    
   public:
      ComplexNumber(T a, T b) : x(a) , y(b) {}        
      void display()  {    std::cout<<x << " + i"<<y<<std::endl;   }
};
template<> ComplexNumber<char>::ComplexNumber(char a, char b) = delete;//<== the right way to delete
int main()
{
    
    ComplexNumber<int> obj1(1,2);
    ComplexNumber<double> obj2(1.0,2.0);
    ComplexNumber<char> obj3('1' , '2');
    return 0;
}
```

which will ends up to

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:19:39: error: use of deleted function ‘ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(T, T) [with T = char]’
     ComplexNumber<char> obj3('1' , '2');
                                       ^ main.cpp:13:12: 
note: declared here  template<> ComplexNumber<char>::ComplexNumber(char a, char b) = delete;
```

You can test it [here](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22//onlinegdb.com/embed/js/-VmDyO4yY?theme=dark%22%3E%3C/script%3E)